# Boost Serialization invoke wrong serialization method

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I have used the `macro` pair of `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(T)` for **header** file and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(T)` for **implementation** file in order to serialize **derived** class from **base** class pointer.

(**note: I have put the macro in all headers and implementation files that need to be serialized including the base class)

However, there is a strange problem that i encountered when serializing till up to specific class. The problem i have is serialization is correct when `saving` but wrong when `loading` which it will invoke different class serialization method.

UPDATED: FYI, after invoking the wrong serialization method from different class, the exception of unregistered class thrown. The code only has problem in `binary_archive` and is working OK for `text_archive` which is confusing for me as i thought if `text_archive` serialization is ok, then `binary_archive` should has no problem. Or i am missing some very distinctive difference that needed to be take care of here.

Some of the code snippet is as below:

FYI, The problem happens when trying to deserialize `SubModelLayer`. `SubModelLayer` also inherits `Node`.

```
template<typename Archive>
void ModelLayer::serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // invoke serialization of the base class 
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Node>(*this);
    //this will actually call the 
    //ModelLayerData<_MODEL_LAYER_VERSION_ONE>::serialize
    //for serialization
    serialize_helper(_modelLayerData, ar, version);
}

template<typename Archive>
void ModelLayerData<_MODEL_LAYER_VERSION_ONE>::serialize(Archive & ar)
{
    ar & _xDimension;
    ar & _yDimension;
    ar & _zDimension;

    if (Archive::is_saving::value)
    {
        int dataType = static_cast<int>(_dataType);
        ar & dataType;
        size_t const totalSize = _xDimension*_yDimension*_zDimension;

        switch (_dataType)
        {
        case DataType::UCHAR:
            ar & boost::serialization::make_array<unsigned char>(_imageData.get(), totalSize);
            break;
        case DataType::USHORT:
            ar & boost::serialization::make_array<unsigned short>(_ushortImageData.get(), totalSize);
            break;
        default:
            std::string message = std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " | " + std::string(__FILE__);
            throw ModelLayerException::InvalidDataException(message);
            break;
        }

        size_t subModelLayerCollectionSize = _subModelLayerCollection.size();
        ar & subModelLayerCollectionSize;
        //submodellayer
        for (auto const &key : _subModelLayerCollection)
        {
            SubModelLayer *subModelLayer = key.second.get();
            ar & subModelLayer; //saving is calling the correct serialization method in SubModelLayer
        }
    }
    if (Archive::is_loading::value) //loading
    {
        int dataType;
        ar & dataType;
        _dataType = static_cast<DataType>(dataType);
        try
        {
            size_t const totalSize = _xDimension*_yDimension*_zDimension;
            switch (_dataType)
            {
            case DataType::UCHAR:
                _imageData.reset(new unsigned char[totalSize]);
                ar & boost::serialization::make_array<unsigned char>(_imageData.get(), totalSize);
                break;
            case DataType::USHORT:
                _ushortImageData.reset(new unsigned short[totalSize]);
                ar & boost::serialization::make_array<unsigned short>(_ushortImageData.get(), totalSize);
                break;
            default:
                std::string message = std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " | " + std::string(__FILE__);
                throw ModelLayerException::InvalidDataException(message);
                break;
            }
            int subModelLayerCollectionSize;
            ar & subModelLayerCollectionSize;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < subModelLayerCollectionSize; i++)
            {
                std::string timestamp;
                std::unique_ptr<SubModelLayer> subModelLayer;
                SubModelLayer * rawSubModelLayer = new SubModelLayer();
                //problem happens here
                ar & rawSubModelLayer; //loading is calling the wrong serialization method which is located in another class
                subModelLayer.reset(rawSubModelLayer);
                timestamp = subModelLayer->getTimestamp();
                _subModelLayerCollection.insert(std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<SubModelLayer>>::value_type(timestamp, std::move(subModelLayer)));
                switch (_dataType)
                {
                case DataType::UCHAR:
                    _subModelLayerCollection.at(timestamp)->setImageData(_imageData.get(), _xDimension, _yDimension, _zDimension);
                    break;
                case DataType::USHORT:
                    _subModelLayerCollection.at(timestamp)->setImageData(_ushortImageData.get(), _xDimension, _yDimension, _zDimension);
                    break;
                default:
                    std::string message = std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " | " + std::string(__FILE__);
                    throw ModelLayerException::InvalidDataException(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::string message = std::string(ex.what()) + " " + std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " | " + std::string(__FILE__);
            throw ModelLayerException::AllocateImageDataException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspected that there might be some problem in registration of derived class due to misuse of API.

My sample output file is as below in which i cant see there is a string identifier of class that tells boost which class to instantiate and deserialize.

```
22 serialization::archive 13 0 1 1
0 0 1 5.714890957e+000 -1.402821732e+001 1.363411617e+001 5.255104303e-001 1.317463517e-001 -1.736424565e-001 8.223928213e-001 1.000000000e+000 1.410727501e+001 2.772170639e+001 2.090770340e+001 7.853981853e-001 1 0 2 1 1
1 1 0 3 1 1
2 10 10 10 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 4 4 1 1
3 10 10 10 0 0 0 10 10 10 0 4
4 10 10 10 0 0 0 10 10 10 0 4
5 10 10 10 0 0 0 10 10 10 0 4
6 10 10 10 0 0 0 10 10 10 0 0 -1.00000000000000000e+000 1.00000000000000000e+000
```

But a little sample that mimics the class structure of mine at coliru produces the output that contains identifier for classes.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/567d455fb020734d

**UPDATE:** attached SubModelLayer header and source as well as SubModelLayerData source.

*SubModelLayer.hpp*

```
//SubModelLayer.hpp    
static const unsigned _SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION = 1;
    static const unsigned _SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_CURRENT_VERSION = _SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION;

template<unsigned version>
class SubModelLayerData;

template<>
class SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION> 
    : public Serializable, Setup
{
public:
    //No OIV object initialization should be done in constructor
    SubModelLayerData();
    ~SubModelLayerData();

    void setup();

    // Inherited via Serializable
    virtual void synchronize();

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar);

    int _xDimension;
    int _yDimension;
    int _zDimension;
    void *_data;
};

class SubModelLayer : public Node
{
public:
    SubModelLayer();
    ~SubModelLayer();
    // Inherited via Node
    virtual void synchronize() override;
    void setImageData(unsigned short * imageData, int const xDimension, int const yDimension, int const zDimension);
    void setImageData(unsigned char * imageData, int const xDimension, int const yDimension, int const zDimension);

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);

    // Inherited via Node
    virtual void setup() override;
    void renderSubModelLayer(int dataByteSize);

    //current version of sceneData
    SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_CURRENT_VERSION> _subModelLayerData;
};

BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(SubModelLayer, _SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_CURRENT_VERSION);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(SubModelLayer);
```

*SubModelLayer.cpp*

```
//SubModelLayer.cpp
template void SubModelLayer::serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive & ar, const unsigned int version);
template void SubModelLayer::serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const unsigned int version);
template void SubModelLayer::serialize(boost::archive::binary_iarchive & ar, const unsigned int version);
template void SubModelLayer::serialize(boost::archive::binary_oarchive & ar, const unsigned int version);


SubModelLayer::SubModelLayer()
    : Node(VArtObjectTypeID::SUBMODEL_LAYER)
{
    setup();
}

SubModelLayer::~SubModelLayer()
{
}

void SubModelLayer::setup()
{
    _subModelLayerData._root = getGroup();
    _subModelLayerData.setup();
    _subModelLayerData._root->setUserData(this);
}

template<typename Archive>
void SubModelLayer::serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // invoke serialization of the base class
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Node>(*this);
    serialize_helper(_subModelLayerData, ar, version);
}

void SubModelLayer::synchronize()
{
    _subModelLayerData.synchronize();
}

void SubModelLayer::setImageData(unsigned short * imageData, int const xDimension, int const yDimension, int const zDimension)
{
    _subModelLayerData._data = imageData;
    _subModelLayerData._xDimension = xDimension;
    _subModelLayerData._yDimension = yDimension;
    _subModelLayerData._zDimension = zDimension;

    renderSubModelLayer(_UNSIGNED_SHORT_BYTE_SIZE);
}

void SubModelLayer::setImageData(unsigned char * imageData, int const xDimension, int const yDimension, int const zDimension)
{
    _subModelLayerData._data = imageData;
    _subModelLayerData._xDimension = xDimension;
    _subModelLayerData._yDimension = yDimension;
    _subModelLayerData._zDimension = zDimension;
    renderSubModelLayer(_UNSIGNED_CHAR_BYTE_SIZE);
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(SubModelLayer);
```

*SubModelLayerData.cpp*

```
//SubModelLayerData.cpp
template void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive & ar);
template void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar);
template void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::serialize(boost::archive::binary_iarchive & ar);
template void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::serialize(boost::archive::binary_oarchive & ar);

SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::SubModelLayerData()
{
    _xDimension = 0;
    _yDimension = 0;
    _zDimension = 0;
}

template<typename Archive>
void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::serialize(Archive & ar)
{
    ar & _xDimension;
    ar & _yDimension;
    ar & _zDimension;
}

SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::~SubModelLayerData()
{
}

void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::synchronize()
{
}

void SubModelLayerData<_SUB_MODEL_LAYER_DATA_VERSION>::setup()
{
}
```

UPDATE: BTW, I am using code below to load and save binary file

```
Scene * scene;
{
    std::ifstream file(projectName, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia{ file };
    ia >> scene;
}
return scene;

{
    std::ofstream ofs(projectName, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive binaryArchive(ofs);
    binaryArchive << scene;
}
```

UPDATED: Call stack shown calling of `text_archive` in `binary_archive` deserialization.

[image]

Code snippet of Boost Serialization Library which i do not understand, problem happens in execution after `if(newbpis_ptr != bpis_ptr)`. Am I violating anything that might result in failure of deserialization.
Lastly, the exception thrown after this method is `Unregistered Class`.

```
template<class Tptr>
static void invoke(Archive & ar, Tptr & t){
    check_load(*t);
    const basic_pointer_iserializer * bpis_ptr = register_type(ar, *t);
    const basic_pointer_iserializer * newbpis_ptr = ar.load_pointer(
        // note major hack here !!!
        // I tried every way to convert Tptr &t (where Tptr might
        // include const) to void * &.  This is the only way
        // I could make it work. RR
        (void * & )t,
        bpis_ptr,
        find
    );
    // if the pointer isn't that of the base class
    if(newbpis_ptr != bpis_ptr){
        t = pointer_tweak(newbpis_ptr->get_eti(), t, *t);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should **not** explicitly `new` an object being deserialized. Pointer serialization handles it automatically. Please post the definition of SubmodelLayer class, its serialization function and all relevant registration macros.

Comment: @n.m. i have attached the required source file although i have shorten it a little bit due to too much irrelevant code that is not related to serialization.

Comment: @n.m. I did try not to new the pointer, yet the same error happens

Comment: This is not the reason of this particular problem, just some indication of perhaps you not fully understanding how this thing works. `ar & ptr` *modifies* `ptr` when loading. Whatever you had in it gets lost. So `ptr = something; ar & ptr` makes no sense when loading.

Comment: @n.m. i still didnt get it. Does that mean the object that I `new` is lost during `ar & ptr` (memory leak) while the syntax is actually instantiate (`new()`) an object then writes the values to it?

Comment: Anyway I don't see anything being serialized through a base class pointer, and you are not saying what other class serialization is invoked at the problematic ine. I'm afraid you need to provide a [mcve]. Your example at coliru doesn't resemble code in the question too much.

Comment: Yes it's a memiry leak.

Comment: @n.m. i will try to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example but i am not sure whether i could still simulate the problem. In the above case, SubModelLayer is not actually serialized through its base class.

Comment: Hi@n.m. I havent reproduce a small example yet, but from my latest testing, the problem only happens on binary_iarchive when loading data while binary_oarchive is perfectly ok. Besides, the code is working ok for `text_oarchive` and `text_iarchive`. BTW, i have also recorrect all the pointer error.

Comment: Working OK with text but not binary archive? This doesn't seem like a straightforward mistake one can make. It could be a bug in boost or a bug in your code that could be virtually anywhere.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry for the late reply, i am trying hard to get back to debugging this issue. Perhaps, updated debugging details could give you some insight on where might go wrong. Thanks.